# Java, Vector not adding character input

Tags: java

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    char input;
    char wrapInput;

    while(true) {
    System.out.print("Enter a char : ");
    input = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
    wrapInput = new Character(input);

    Vector<Character> characters = new Vector<Character>();
    characters.add(wrapInput);

    for (int j = 0; j < characters.size(); j++) {
        System.out.print(characters.capacity());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print(characters.get(j));
    }
    System.out.println();
    }

}
```

The purpose of the code is to prompt the user for a character, read it, wrap it in a Character object, and add it to a Vector of objects. However, for some reason the vector is not adding the character inputs when you go to input the next character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because every time through your loop, you're making a new `Vector`, which is initially empty.  You're then adding the character that was input, and printing out what's in it.

The change you need to make is to move the line

```
Vector<Character> characters = new Vector<Character>();
```

up to before

```
while(true) {
```

so that you only create a new `Vector` once.

You may also want to add some mechanism to allow the user to escape from the loop.